# rhc setup Doctype error

Tags: installation, openshift

I have:
-Windows 10 
-ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
-git version 2.6.4.windows.1

When I type in: `rhc setup` and then i try to log in i get this:

```
 use the server for OpenShift Online: openshift.redhat.com.
    Enter the server hostname: |openshift.redhat.com| here is my login

    You can add more servers later using 'rhc server'.
    RSA 1024 bit CA certificates are loaded due to old openssl compatibility

    An unexpected error occurred: invalid character at "<!DOCTYPE "
```

I need little help here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this step "`Enter the server hostname: |openshift.redhat.com|`", just hit enter, don't type anything there.  If you type something else there it's going to try to connect to that and it won't work.